# Following questions on Stack Overflow, without having to favorite them

Tags: support, stack-overflow

So.., What if the question is not actually favorite for me, but I still want to follow the question related activity?

I am sorry, if the query is already answered somewhere in the site documentation, but I didn't find it.

Comment: It's ok to favorite a question even if it's really not your favorite (we won't tell anyone!) but if that feels too wrong I recommend your browser's bookmarking functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options;

First, there is a question feed on each question, which you can use to view it in your favorite RSS reader, like Google Reader (sniffle!... sorry; that's being closed down!)

Next; don't worry about using favorites. There's nothing that says you have to use them for literal favorites. You can use them for anything you want to save to check out later.

Comment: I use third option as copy the link into a file for future user :) however its bit lengthy when there are lots of links :P

Comment: why did this question get migrated to meta.SO ? why not meta.webapps ?

Comment: @AbZy Because it's applicable to *all* Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks. I understand I can use favorites for following a question. As it (feature name) didn't reflect the purpose (follow-ups), I thought there could be some another feature for the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

And the third option is to bookmark those links. Which I always do than adding it to favorites because even if I'm not signed in, I can still able to find the links quickly.

Comment: And the link will not one day disappear when the question is deleted due to change in policy.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use session restore in your browser, just don't close the tab so you can check it back later.